# Site displays as blank on mobile phones

Tags: html, css, ios, mobile

A site that we worked on that used to display on iPhone and Blackberry now shows up as blank on both.  However, it does display as usual on iPad.  To be clear, we never developed a specific mobile site, but it did show up as is.  The site can be found at www.ambit-consulting.com.  Any ideas?

Comment: It shows up for me, on iPhone 3/iOS4.x If you're having trouble with iPhone display it's worth enabling the debug console (Settings > Safari > Developer > Debug console).

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on the iOS simulator which emulates iOS4.2 and it looks fine.